# Select data for "some value" if data null then select data for field IS NULL

Tags: php, mysql, select, null

Here I have a query which returns price for respective condition. What I am doing now.
Here I am having conditon where I am checking **event_id is NULL or event_id = "some value"** ... what I think is wrong I want to fetch data for the rows where if there is data exist for "some value" then it should return data for only those if there is no data for "some value" then it should check for null.

**Here I want to query data for event_id**

1. **event_id is some int so it should return data for event_id**
2. **if for (1) the data is null theen it should select data for event_id IS NULL**

**How can I do this thing by query?**

Query 1 (checks for event_id) :

```
SELECT  
`tpliv`.`ticket_sub_type_id` AS  `ticketSubTypeId` ,
`tst`.`ticket_sub_type` AS  `ticketSubType` , 
`tpliv`.`price` AS  `ticketPrice` ,
`tpliv`.`tax` AS  `ticketTax` , 
`tpliv`.`ticket_price_list_item_vendor_id` AS `ticketPriceListId` ,
`tpliv`.`ticket_price_list_id` AS `ticketPriceList` , 
`tpliv`.`fee` AS  `ticketFee` ,  `tpliv`.`status` AS  `status` 
FROM  `ticket_price_list_item_vendor`  `tpliv` 
JOIN  `ticket_price_list`  `tpl` ON tpl.ticket_price_list_id =tpliv.ticket_price_list_id
AND tpl.event_group_id =  "45"
AND tpl.vendor_id =  "442"
AND tpl.dinner_category_id IS NULL 
AND tpl.status =1
AND tpl.event_id =  "39152"
AND tpl.seat_section_id IS NULL 
AND tpl.vendor_sub_group_id IS NULL 
AND tpl.vip_seat_id IS NULL 
AND tpl.seat_block_section_id IS NULL 
AND tpl.is_upsale IS NULL 
JOIN  `ticket_sub_types`  `tst` ON tst.ticket_sub_type_id = tpliv.ticket_sub_type_id
AND tst.status =1
JOIN  `ticket_sub_type_vendor`  `tstv` ON tstv.ticket_sub_type_id=tst.ticket_sub_type_id
AND tstv.status =1
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Query 2 (checks for event_id IS NULL) :

```
SELECT  
`tpliv`.`ticket_sub_type_id` AS  `ticketSubTypeId` ,
`tst`.`ticket_sub_type` AS  `ticketSubType` , 
`tpliv`.`price` AS  `ticketPrice` ,
`tpliv`.`tax` AS  `ticketTax` , 
`tpliv`.`ticket_price_list_item_vendor_id` AS `ticketPriceListId` ,
`tpliv`.`ticket_price_list_id` AS `ticketPriceList` , 
`tpliv`.`fee` AS  `ticketFee` ,  `tpliv`.`status` AS  `status` 
FROM  `ticket_price_list_item_vendor`  `tpliv` 
JOIN  `ticket_price_list`  `tpl` ON tpl.ticket_price_list_id =tpliv.ticket_price_list_id
AND tpl.event_group_id =  "45"
AND tpl.vendor_id =  "442"
AND tpl.dinner_category_id IS NULL 
AND tpl.status =1
AND  tpl.event_id IS NULL
AND tpl.seat_section_id IS NULL 
AND tpl.vendor_sub_group_id IS NULL 
AND tpl.vip_seat_id IS NULL 
AND tpl.seat_block_section_id IS NULL 
AND tpl.is_upsale IS NULL 
JOIN  `ticket_sub_types`  `tst` ON tst.ticket_sub_type_id = tpliv.ticket_sub_type_id
AND tst.status =1
JOIN  `ticket_sub_type_vendor`  `tstv` ON tstv.ticket_sub_type_id=tst.ticket_sub_type_id
AND tstv.status =1
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

So what I want to do is that will execute query 1 if return data is null then execute query to and retrieve data.

**Is it possible to handle these queries in one query?**

I want to combine this two query in one query .... for following scenario

1. In first query if I get data (not null) I do not have to check second query
2. If I get data null in first query then should return data from query two ...
3. I want to combine both queries and make one query

The real world scenario (Why I can not use **(event_id IS NULL OR event_id = "soem value")** )

- If for "some event_id" I get 3 rows in return data
- And for event_id IS NULL I get 2 rows ...
- In this scenario I only want 3 rows which come with "some event id" and I don't need other data...
- If  for "some event_id" I get null data only then and then I want to use query 2 to retrieve data..

Comment: Please have a look at your question. Its not clear what you are asking. Try and reword the question so it makes sense to somebody that is not looking over your shoulder and already knows what you are trying to do.

Comment: @RiggsFolly i have updated question... please check...

Comment: Surely you just need to `AND ( tpl.event_id = "39152" OR tpl.event_id IS NULL)`

Comment: but here if query 1 returns data then i should not execute query 2...  means if query 1 has 3 row in return and query 2 has 2 rows in return data in that scenario i should only get 3 rows where tpl.event_id = "39152" not for null...  if for tpl.event_id = "39152" this condtion gets null data only then and then i have to check for tpl.event_id IS NULL

Comment: Well assuming all the other selection criteria are the same that should allow you to use one query to get all 5 lines. You then just check the value of tpl.event_id in your PHP code and react accordingly if its value is NULL.

Comment: no that's not problem ...  problem is the value of returning data i want to give priority to the data (which has event_id) if there is no data with (event_id) then and then want to retrive data for (event_id IS NULL)

Comment: So add a `ORDER BY tpl.event_id DESC` and you will get the data back with the NULLS last.

Comment: k.. yeah that s right ... thanks..